# Does Hangouts support the Invitation API?

Tags: google-hangouts

Is there Hangouts Invitation API?
Like this:
1) Click on invitation link with target's gmail
2) Hangouts chat room starts

I don't think these APIs are supported.
But, I want to make sure.
Please advice me :)

Comment: _I don't think these APIs are supported..._ Read their docs?

Comment: Yes, i did. but i couldn't find